# JSF2 on Jetty gives randomly 'zip file closed' but works when running from maven jetty plugin (jetty:run)

Tags: jsf-2, jetty

my JSF web app is giving randomly error: "zip file closed" when accessing files (like images, css, js). It is deployed on Jetty 7. It looks like some of those files are not loaded (some images are missing on a page).

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:403)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.entries(ZipFile.java:298)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.entries(JarFile.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.JarFileResource.list(JarFileResource.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.ResourceCollection.list(ResourceCollection.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource.getListHTML(Resource.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.sendDirectory(DefaultServlet.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:564)
```

When I run it from maven plugin (7.x) with jetty:run or jetty:run-war then I do not get any  error. 
What's more, accessing root path of web context gives that "zip file closed" error only when running on standalone jetty, but no such error when running from maven pluging, then is those directory view.

My web.xml:

```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

pom.xml:

```
  ....
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
....
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.5.1.v20110908</version>

        <configuration>
            <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.3</version>
            </dependency>                    
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Any idea what could it be?

Comment: We are experiencing the same problems on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP1, we have tried to downgrade jetty.maven.plugin to 7.2.2 but the problem persists. The zip errors are random and an reload in the browser fixes the problem for the user (meaning missing img or css is fetched). However, for us that is not a solution. We have verified that the resources are unpacked on the file system and that Jetty has permission to access them. Anyone else with same problem, or preferably an solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty looks for your resources in the jar files in WEB-INF/lib. When it searches jsf-impl.jar it is somehow closed, probably by a JSF request. Perhaps jsf does its own resource handling and messes about with the files itself.

Anyway, the solution seems to be to move the jsf jars out of the war-file. Set your jsf dependency scope to provided so maven does not package them in the war file, and get them on the server, probably in the lib folder in jetty standalone.

Answer (score 6):

This [issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364936) has been fixed in jetty-7.6.0.RC2. The bug is caused by the JVM caching jar url connection streams.

According to the bug report, you will need to also add the following to the jetty.xml:

```
 <Set class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource" name="defaultUseCaches">false</Set>
```

Comment: I am using `jetty-serverlet`, will the 7.6.16 of it fix this issue?

Comment: According to the issue tracker, should be fixed in versions >= 7.5.4. Are you seeing it in 7.6.16?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it by going to `etc\webdefault.xml` and changing this param to `false`:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>gzip</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```