# How do I create a new eclipse project for jetty from a tomcat based project and versioned with svn/subclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, tomcat, jetty, subclipse

Is there a simple way to solve the following problem?
I have an eclipse workspace with a dynamic web project shared in svn using subclipse plug-in.
The project is based on tomcat7.
Now I would like to move the project to jetty8, leaving the source files in the same svn repository. Is that possible?
I don't want to kill the previous project on tomcat but I would like to mantain both projects.

I tryed importing the tomcat project into a new workspace as is but it's doesn't work.
Which steps should I do if there is a smothless procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved in this way:

1. create a branch of the tomcat project in the repository
2. import the tomcat project into a new workspace
3. switch the project to the previously created branch
4. as the project cannot run on jetty as is, change the targeted runtimes property to jetty
5. as eclipse does not include all the jetty jars in the classpath, add the missing ones from the jetty lib directory
6. fix some other stuff, like [JSF2 on Jetty gives randomly 'zip file closed' but works when running from maven jetty plugin (jetty:run)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715985/)

and now it works perfectly!
Hope this could help someone else.