# jsf lib closed on jetty 8

Tags: java, jsf-2, jetty

I am trying to deploy application using jetty, but the problem is that it is not loading images, but only few.

Application is packaged in war using Maven.

I have followed this [doc](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-zip-exceptions)

Added this context:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
 <Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
   <Set name="contextPath">/game</Set>
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/game.war</Set>   
  <Set name="extractWAR">true</Set>
   <Set name="copyWebDir">true</Set>
   <Set name="tempDirectory"><Property name="jetty.home" default="."/>/work/game</Set>
</Configure>
```

created work directory in home folder so jetty is unpacking all my files in specified folder.

And created this jetty-webapp.xml

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
<Ref id="DeploymentManager">
      <Call id="webappprovider" name="addAppProvider">
        <Arg>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider">
            <Set name="monitoredDirName"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/webapps</Set>
            <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><Property name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/webdefault.xml</Set>
            <Set name="tempDir"><Property name="jetty.home" default="."/>/work</Set>
            <Set name="scanInterval">1</Set>
            <Set name="contextXmlDir"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/contexts</Set>
    <Set name="extractWars">true</Set>      
          </New>
        </Arg>
      </Call>
</Ref>
```

But still some resources usually is not available because of zip file is closed exception. This is happening when jetty is trying to access faces jars

Comment: perhaps look up the zip file is closed exception. also, you should be using WAR's not Zips

Comment: Problem is solved - solution was to add conflicted jars to jetty.home/lib/ext

Comment: I'm curious, how come it needed to be added there?

Comment: According to this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7905896/1797171) jsf jar files are somehow closed so they need to be added to this folder :)